# Python 3 UnboundLocalError while accessing attribute of wrapping function

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, scope, runtime-error

I implemented a debug function to measure the time it takes to execute methods.
For some reason, I get a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ident' referenced before assignment` when accessing the respective name in `measure()`:

```
def time(func_or_id, func=None):
    """Decorator to measure time

    Usage:
        @time
        def my_method():
            ...

    or with a specific identifier:
        @time('my_identifier')
        def my_method():
            ...

    or with a uuid:
        @time(True)
        def my_method():
            ...
    """
    ident = None
    uuid_flag = False

    if func is None:
        func = func_or_id
    elif func_or_id is True:
        uuid_flag = True
    else:
        ident = str(func_or_id)

    try:
        fname = func.__name__
    except AttributeError:
        fname = 'Unknown function'

    def measure(*args, **kwargs):
        """Measure time that a function takes to run"""
        if uuid_flag:
            ident = str(uuid4())
        if ident:    # <- Causes the exception!
            fname = ' '.join(fname, ''.join(['(', ident, ')']))
        print('Starting to measure time of:', fname)
        start = datetime.now()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        duration = datetime.now() - start
        print(fname, 'took:', duration)
        return result

    return measure
```

I do not understand why this happens, since the checking on `uuid_flag`, which is declared right after `ident` does not cause any problems:

```
def time(func_or_id, func=None):
    """Decorator to measure time

    Usage:
        @time
        def my_method():
            ...

    or with a specific identifier:
        @time('my_identifier')
        def my_method():
            ...

    or with a uuid:
        @time(True)
        def my_method():
            ...
    """
    #ident = None
    uuid_flag = False

    if func is None:
        func = func_or_id
    elif func_or_id is True:
        uuid_flag = True
    #else:
    #    ident = str(func_or_id)

    try:
        fname = func.__name__
    except AttributeError:
        fname = 'Unknown function'

    def measure(*args, **kwargs):
        """Measure time that a function takes to run"""
        if uuid_flag:
            ident = str(uuid4())
        #if ident:
        #    fname = ' '.join(fname, ''.join(['(', ident, ')']))
        print('Starting to measure time of:', fname)
        start = datetime.now()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        duration = datetime.now() - start
        print(fname, 'took:', duration)
        return result

    return measure
```

What am I doing wrong accessing `ident`?

Comment: You are using `ident` in an assignment, making it a local name.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the reference to the fibonacci problem.
Adding `nonlocal ident, uuid_flag, fname, func` as the first line of `measure()` solved the issue.

Comment: You only need to use `nonlocal` for names that you bind to; in your case you only bind to `ident` and `fname`; the rest of the names are already going to be taken from the surrounding scope.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.
PS: I also need `fname`

Comment: Yeah, just saw that; I didn't make a thorough enough sweep.